# Core Data NSDate Comparison

Tags: iphone, datetime, core-data

I am storing a date attribute in Core Data using the datePicker on the iPhone. I want to then compare the date that matches a certain date using == but I can't get it to work. The greater than and less than seem to working fine though.

At first I was storing the date directly from the datePicker which also included the time information. So I used the NSCalendar to strip of the time and just store the date.

Similarly I take the rhs of the predicate and run it through NSCalendar to extract just the date and do the comparison and I still can't get the == to work.

Tried doing a NSLog of the date being stored in CoreData and the date being compared and they look exactly the same 
2010-06-19 00:00:00 -7:00

Any pointers will be appreciated.

EDIT:
I am trying to do the comparison in CoreData using the NSEqualToPredicateOperatorType passed into the

```
+ (NSPredicate *)predicateWithLeftExpression:(NSExpression *)lhs rightExpression:(NSExpression *)rhs modifier:(NSComparisonPredicateModifier)modifier type:(NSPredicateOperatorType)type options:(NSUInteger)options
```

with the lhs being the keypath to entity.dateAttribute
and rhs being [NSExpression expressionForConstantValue:myDate];

PS: I had the above code and then realized that myDate consisted of a time component so I modified the above code to extract only the day, month and year and use it to send it to NSExpression.

Similarly while saving the date, I made sure that I am extracting only the date, month and year and passing it to CoreDate effectively making the time 00:00:00 (I hope!)

Answer (score 0):

The [`compare:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDate/compare%3a) method in the `NSDate` class will give you what you are looking for.

> **Return Value**
>
> If:
>
> - **The receiver and anotherDate are exactly equal to each other,
>     `NSOrderedSame`**
> - The receiver is later in time than anotherDate, `NSOrderedDescending`
> - The receiver is earlier in time than anotherDate, `NSOrderedAscending`.

In general, if you're trying to compare two objects, look for a class/instance method to do so. Comparing two object pointers with `==` will just compare the pointers themselves, which is not what you want.